# Sorting in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, sorting

I'm very new to Ruby on rails. I try to edit the following api. 
I want to sorting "can_go" which is true are shown at the top of list.
I added this row before sending data, but the result is still order by "user_id".

```
user_infos.sort {  |a, b| - (a['can_go']<=>b['can_go'])  }
```

Could you please tell me how to change this source?
 Thank you. Here is the source.

```
def send_user_infos cmd_id, users: []
    users_app_modes = UsersAppMode.where(user_id: users.map(&:id),
                                     app_mode: AppMode.mode1).includes(:user)
    user_infos = users_app_modes.map do |ua|
      u = ua.user
      c = alive_connections[u]
      state = c ? c.state : :logoff
      begin
      {
        user_id: u.id.to_s,
        name: u.display_name,
        score: (ua.total_superior_score.ceil rescue 150),
        state: state,
        format_state: state,
        can_go: c ? true : false,
      }
      rescue => e
        logger.error e.to_s
        nil
      end
    end.compact
    user_infos.sort {  |a, b| - (a['can_go']<=>b['can_go'])  }
    send_data "users_info #{user_infos.map { |i| CGI.escape(i.to_json) }.join " "}", cmd_id: cmd_id 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not getting the results you want because you're not assigning the sorted `user_infos` back into the `user_infos` variable. You can do the following:

```
user_infos = user_infos.sort {|a, b| - (a['can_go'] <=> b['can_go']) }
# -or-
user_infos.sort! {|a, b| - (a['can_go'] <=> b['can_go']) }
```

The first version of [`sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort) creates a new array, which requires assignment; the second version [`sort!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort-21) sorts in place and therefore doesn't require the assignment.